# Grammaticality of "by the bus" when the bus is the only choice

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

Can the expression "by the bus" be used to specify how I go home when it is the only method to be used?

Comment: "probably duplicates one or more"? Every question "probably duplicates one or another, on one or the other resources online" :)

Comment: user35828 Try to understand the difference between "Take a bus" and "Take the bus".

Comment: Question is answered in [“By the bus” or “on the bus”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92597) and similar questions in "LINKED" section in sidebar.   ([1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251)[2](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88303)[3](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83383) [4](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95496))

Comment: I read "by the bus" as "near to the bus", but that could be just me.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["By foot" vs. "on foot"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17943/by-foot-vs-on-foot)

Answer (score 1):

If there is just one way to reach your home, then I could get there

- by bus
- on the bus
- using the bus

If you needed to tell me **which** bus I needed to catch by quoting a route number, then it would be usual to include the article -- "by the 64 bus".